# How can I display the data in a view with Angularjs and NODEJS and MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, angularjs, node.js

I am trying to display the data in a mysql table

I fall below my app.js node code

```
app.get('/api/todos', function(req, res) {
connection.query('SELECT * FROM pacsdb.ae',function(err, data){
  if(err)
  {
    res.send(err);
  }
  res.send(data);
  //res.render('pacientes',{data:data});
  console.log(data);
});
});
```

The console if it shows me the data obtained by the SQL but the problem comes in the view with angular

Here I leave you the code of app.js of angularjs

```
Var myApp = angular.module ('angularTodo', []);

MyApp.controller ('mainController', ['$ scope', '$ http', function ($ scope, $ http)

$ Http.get ('/ api / all'). Then (function (value) {
$ Scope.pacientes = value;
}). Finally (function () {
$ Scope.example7 + = "(Finally called)";
});
}]);
```

And the view

```
<Table class = "table" style = "border: 2px">
<Thead>
<Th> ID; </ Th>
</ Thead>
<Tbody>
<Tr ng-repeat = "data in pacientes">
<Td> {{data.pk}} </ td>

</ Tr>
</ Tbody>
</ Table>
```

The problem is that when data [0] .pk if the data is displayed at position 0, but I want to display all the data in the mysql table, but so data.pk does not display anything in the view

I'm sorry for my English.

UPDATE

I already found the solution, my problem was the controller angularjs add the res.data to take the complete arrangement, I leave here the code

```
var myApp = angular.module('angularTodo', []);

myApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http){

   $http.get('/api/todos').then(function(res) {
       $scope.pacientes = res.data;
   }).finally(function() {
       $scope.example7 += " (Finally called)";
   });

}]);
```

Comment: You have a typo mistake. data in patients (you wrote date)

Comment: I was wrong to type the code here, but I still have the problem

Comment: update the question and show us what's inside "value", in the "then" function